# How to help a service increase its importance

Tags: android

I have written a messenger application and for last steps, I'm trying to keep my service which keeps connection, listens to it and does all writing jobs alive, when i check the importance of applications using `ActivityManager`, my app's importance is just 100, which is apparently lowest in the list. How can I increase my service's priority so it is one of the last to get killed and one of first to get restarted?

I have also tried this :

```
Thread.currentThread().setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);

android.os.Process.setThreadPriority(-19);
```

I am not sure if this is doing anything.

Comment: possible duplicate of [High priority Android services](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7408212/high-priority-android-services)

Comment: Bringing a Service Process to Foreground has Alot of Consequences, which are not acceptable for a messenger, and i dont want the everlasting notification hatement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Using ActivityManager , My App's Importance is Just 100, which is appearantly lowest in the list

No, that is highest in the list. [A value of 100 is `IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.html#IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND), and is reserved for a process showing the foreground UI.

> can Some one Please Help me how can i increase my Service's Priority so it be one of lasts to get killed and one of firsts to get restarted?

It is already driving the foreground UI; it cannot get more important than that.

In general, a process with a service that is not in the foreground will have [`IMPORTANCE_SERVICE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.html#IMPORTANCE_SERVICE). Your only option to improve upon that would be to use `startForeground()`.

> Bringing a Service Process to Foreground has Alot of Consequences, which are not acceptable for a messenger, and i dont want the everlasting notification hatement

Then you will need to live with your existing importance.

> i have also tried this :

Changing the priority of a thread does not affect the importance of the process.

Comment: but in the list i can see importance of 200, 300 and 400 !

Comment: @user3597152: For whatever reason, lower numbers mean higher importance.

Comment: dude 1 more question , am i right about not running xmpp connection on the foreground?

Comment: @user3597152: Foreground services have their uses. Music players will use a foreground service, with the service actually playing the music. The VOIP app that I use (CSipSimple) uses a foreground service while I am on WiFi, to be able to receive SIP signals of incoming VOIP calls from the SIP server. Whether a foreground service is justifiable in your case, I cannot say.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to control importance, I have tested when the importance changes for an app process, and found that when you have an activity running a service in the foreground, the importance is set to IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND[100].

When you pause the activity with the service running, it'll be IMPORTANCE_PERCEPTIBLE[130] for a split second, then the importance is set to IMPORTANCE_BACKGROUND[400], but if you kill the activity using the task manager, the service will continue to run, but the importance is set to IMPORTANCE_SERVICE[300].

But in regards to what you wanted to do, CommonsWare's solution is pretty much it, unless you use Google Cloud Messaging, which (from what I understand) should run in the background.

**Edit:**

Forgot to mention that if you also list the service in a different process in the manifest, for example:

`<service android:name=".MyService"
                 android:process=":processname" />`

then the importance will be at IMPORTANCE_SERVICE[300].