# GCM service is deleted with cache clearing

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I have a problem with Google Cloud Messaging:

The test smartphone that I use does not have a big RAM and sometimes it deletes also the GCM service of my app that should receive the messages. Sometimes my GCM service works well only during 1 or 2 hours and then is automatically switched off (when RAM is forcibly cleared).

But the requierement of my app is to receive GCM messages always or at least to have an opportunity to have longer sessions (10-12 hours). What can I set up in my app or smartphone to have a relieable GCM service?

The smartphone doesn't see any services in my app. Here is a screenshot where you can compare my app with watsapp:

[image: my app vs. watsapp]

My smarphone uses MIUI process manager.

Here is my Manifest part about GCM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="my.app.path" >    

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
 <!-- ... other permissions -->

<permission
    android:name="my.app.path.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="my.app.path.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<application
    ...>
     <!-- ... activites... -->

    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="my.app.path" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>      

    <service
        android:name=".MyGcmListener"
        android:exported="false"
        android:enabled="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

</application>

</manifest>
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: You might use `startService()` or `startForeground()` to let your service keep running, so the SO wont reclaim it when memory needed, you can see [this   Stackoverflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7408275/4195406) for more details.

Comment: @ztan, thank you, it can help. Do you have occasionally a link to a code snippet?

Comment: @ztan, probably I cannot use startForeground() since I cannot override the service methos onStartCommand() (it is defined as final in the parent class GcmListenerService)

Comment: Your app info list shows two instances of Google Play services running.  Is that normal?  On my devices (LG, Motorola, Samsung) I only see one.

Answer (score 1):

If your app stops receiving messages after a few hours, I suspect the problem is not caused by there being no instance of `GcmListenerService`.  When a GCM message is received by a client, the message is passed to the instance of `GcmReceiver` declared in your app's manifest.  `GcmReceiver` is a `WakefulBroadcastReceiver`.  `GcmReceiver` then delivers the message to the subclass of `GcmListenerService` you have implemented in your app. I am guessing the `GcmReceiver` delivers the message using `startService()`, which will create an instance of the service if one does not exist.  If the system destroys the service because of memory pressure, it will be recreated when a new message is received.

Comment: And what do you mean? That I imagined my problem? That in fact I receive all my messages and do not see them?

Comment: Or doe you mean that GcmReceiver is deleted? What can I do with it?

Comment: I know nothing about MIUI.  If it changes the standard Android behavior for management of app processes and components, then my comments may not be valid.  To help me better understand the problem, please explain how you know a GCM message is received:  a notification, a log message, some change to app data?  Also, please describe the events that lead to the problem.  For example: app is started from launcher and messages are received, app goes into background for many hours, message is sent to app while it is in background and is not received.

Comment: What version of Android is the problem occurring on?  Note that Android 6.0 introduced Doze mode, which affects GCM message receipt -- described in [this documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html#using_gcm).  Whether using 6.0 or not, you might want to try making your messages [high priority](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/concept-options#setting-the-priority-of-a-message) to see if they are then received.

Comment: Do your messages specify [time_to_live](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/concept-options#ttl) or `delay_while_idle`?  I guessing they do not, resulting in the default behavior.

Comment: the problem is that the MIUI in fact changes the standard android behaviour. That is what my question is about. 
Ususally I send a notification when the message is received and in this case I do not see any notifications. I have two test phones that work synchronously: one - with standard Anrdoid - receives all the messages and the other - with MIUI - is dead after 1-2 hours.

Comment: My question actually was about this unstandard behaviour: the more people susing these chinese smartphones with miui support. And for me as for Android developer is relevant to know what I can do to maintain my app on different types of devices