# Check if GcmReceiver works

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I have some problems with my Android application when my test smartphone cleans cache: my app does not receive any messages any more (more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33612007/gcm-service-is-deleted-with-cache-clearing)).

At the beginning I thought that my gcm listener service is also cleared with memory but in fact the problem can be deeper: the GcmReceiver (which should receive a message and give it further to MyListenerService) could be cleaned from RAM (see one of the comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33627053/how-to-run-gcmlistenerservice-in-foreground))

**How can I check if my GcmReceiver still works. What can I do to support it?

Can I set it to run in foreground or to be always activated?**

Traditionally: my manifest about GCM (`MyGcmLister`.class extends `GcmListenerService`.class)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="my.app.path" >    

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<!-- ... other permissions -->

<permission
android:name="my.app.path.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="my.app.path.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<application
...>
 <!-- ... activites... -->

<receiver
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
    android:exported="true"
    android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <category android:name="my.app.path" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>      

<service
    android:name=".MyGcmListener"
    android:exported="false"
    android:enabled="true" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>

</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: I think if you wanna check if your GCM is working, you can `post` a `Http request` to your device. You can try to use `postman`. For more info, please refer here:https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http

Comment: Post the logcat output for the interval during which you expect to receive messages and receive none.