# GCM receives too many messages at once

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I have a qestion about Android processes behavoiur and GCM Listener Service.

As I have already described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33612007/gcm-service-is-deleted-with-cache-clearing), I had a problem with my GCM notification which appeared on some test devices: sometimes the service worked and received messages during only 2-3 hours.

This problem was partly solved whan I added 'startService()'-method to my MainActivity.

```
this.startService(new Intent(context, MyGcmListener.class));
```

Now a session of my service continues longer. But another problem occured since this new app version was released.

The messages don't come one by one and actualized in time. The app process falls asleep and can awake only one time per hour. That's why sometimes I receive up to 15 messages at once although they have not been sent at the same time.

How can I make the process not fell asleep and always stay awake?

This is my manifest part about GCM:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<!-- ... other permissions -->

<permission
android:name="my.app.path.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="my.app.path.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<application
...>
 <!-- ... activites... -->

<receiver
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
    android:exported="true"
    android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <category android:name="my.app.path" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>      

<service
    android:name=".MyGcmListener"
    android:exported="false"
    android:enabled="true" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>

</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: are you receiving duplicate messages?

Comment: @human123,  In general not. The messages in one "consignment" are not all equal. The problem is that they are just pushed at once although they should have come at different times.

Comment: You can try to `set the lifespan of a message` here: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/concept-options#ttl and also use the `collapsible` messages if you needed. https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/concept-options#collapsible_and_non-collapsible_messages